# Need clarification of extracting CSV file using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, codec

I have a simple csv file name log.csv that displays logging in time which is aqquired from a hardware device. It is shown as below when opened using excel and Notepad++.

[image: Opened in Excel]

[image: Opened in Notepad++]

First question being that why is there additional zeroes appeared in Notepad++ and when doing extraction in python.

When I first try it using the basic code from csv, I've gotten an error of _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

```
import csv
with open('log.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')

    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

I have also tried changing the delimiter to ' ' but no luck.Some googling later, found a workaround and it is regarding some sort of codecs.

```
import csv
import codecs

csvReader = csv.reader(codecs.open('log.csv', 'rU', ,utf-16'))

for row in csvReader:
    print (row)
```

This lets me print out some data but is there a workaround to this or I'll just have to format it individually?

[image: Using Codecs]

Comment: @pnuts Yes you're right! How clueless am I! It has to do with the encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found a way for this. The approach is to convert the file from utf-16 to utf-8 before accessing it and works well with the code

```
import csv
with open('log.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')

    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

And the reason why thoese zeroes appear is due to the encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Excel may have applied formatting to show your data differently.  What your Notepad++ and Python sees are the exact values.  Your file seems tab delimited, you should still use `delimiter='\t'` for a start.  Try adding it to your `reader()` function:

```
import csv
import codecs

csvReader = csv.reader(codecs.open('log.csv', 'rU', ,utf-16'), delimiter="\t")
```